# required or required = "required"

Tags: html, required

Am I right in saying required is an empty attribute and doesn't require a value but xHTML prefers that it has one to be complete. Seems to work fine without ="required" on all pages I've created, I just wondered if perhaps certain browsers interpret them differently.

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: please post only 1 question (or better to say topic) per thread

Comment: It's only one question is there a difference between required and required ="required"...

Comment: I can't believe people don't know what the question is or think there are two questions.

Answer (score 10):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz3nQ/)***

There is no difference from a rendering perspective. But if you are going to be looking in the future for these required elements, it helps to have a value to test for.

> Required
>   This attribute specifies that the user must fill in a value before submitting a form. It cannot be used when the type attribute is hidden, image, or a button type (submit, reset, or button). The :optional and :required CSS pseudo-classes will be applied to the field as appropriate. <sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)</sup>

Comment: Cheers @TravisJ thats exactly how I perceived it obviously I could use if statements inside my JSP classes to check if each field is empty but when you have the sheer amount of fields I do then the if statement would be absolutely ridiculous. It only tests for text I have a date picker and I know it doesn't work for that but that's okay.

Comment: _"But if you are going to be looking in the future for these required elements, it helps to have a value to test for."_
Maybe just use [Element.hasAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute) for that? It is >=IE8.